# Connecting usb wifi dongle for wireless SD card with Ethernet for internet

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, sd-card

my windows 10 computer at work is connected to the internet and network via Ethernet.

However what I’d like to do, if possible is use a USB wifi dongle to connect the computer to the EZ share wifi enabled SD card inside my DSLR camera. So that I can wirelessly send photos from the SD card to the computer.

Can anyone help walk me through what I need to do to make this work ? Thanks!

Comment: Can the SD card be removed (normally yes to use a different SD card). Remove it, put it in a USB adapter and plug that into your work computer. That will work. Otherwise you may need to put the camera on the work network and network admins may frown on that.

Comment: @John At my $job we are forbidden to attach any USB devices to our work computers. I can't even use my own tracker ball mouse - fortunately my RSI from using an ordinary mouse has not returned over the last few years - but I find a tracker ball mouse much easier to use.

Comment: Yeah I can remove the sd card and put it into the computer but that’s fine. I’m looking to wirelessly tether it however hence the question. I can ask admin to set things up for me so that’s not a problem